# Drywall mud on ethernet connectors

Tags: drywall-mud

We are in the process of renovating our house and I ran CAT6 cable to an area with plans to put a network switch there.  I now find that the drywall people did not try and protect the connectors and they are caked in the stuff.  Yes. I know I should have covered them... What will dissolve the mud?  Anything?  I would like to avoid cutting the connectors off and re-doing as they were factory cables.

Comment: "Factory cables" hmm - were these patch cables actually rated for in-wall use? Most are not. In-wall wiring rarely has any connectors factory applied, since it's expected to be put into jacks (and you put the jacks in after the drywall and paint folks are done.) On the next one, use conduit  - Then you can put the cables themselves in after the drywall and paint are done, but more importantly you'll be able to replace them when the "next thing" comes along without having to remodel.

Answer (score 2):

Water is useful to soften drywall mud.  Be aware, however, that it may take some time.

You might try a wet rag placed over the connector and then try to remove the bulk of the material with tweezers or a small tool.  Be careful not to bend any of the pins inside the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get to the root of the problem.   You mudded and it kind of looked like this.

[image]

And if someone goes to this site they may read this...

[When drywalling, do the pros cover electrical boxes, or work around them?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/when-drywalling-do-the-pros-cover-electrical-boxes-or-work-around-them)

**(sorry to say this answer is EXTREMELY wrong)**

Pros use this...

[image]

Yes you simply wad up a bunch of newspaper and stuff the hell out of each box.   It should be sticking out.   The guy mudding can do whatever he wants.   You keep it in there during sanding too.   At the last stage of sanding, pull it and then use a knife/saw (I used a utility knife) to cut out any extra pieces which is usually not much or just a sliver here and there.

For things that get mud on them I usually just try to pick the pieces out or rub them between finger to break apart.   If that does work a small tap with a hammer.   After it breaks apart clean it with a wet rag... it can air dry.

But the entire issue is solved with less the 50 cents of left over newspaper.